# Restore File Permissions on CrunchBang Linux

Tags: debian, file-permissions

I'm running #! linux x64 Waldorf.

While setting up Magento (the e-commerce software) for local testing and development, I ran the following command:

```
find . exec chmod 755 {} /;
```

This was an admittedly unexperienced modification to the instructions here: [http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowladge-base/entry/install-privs-before](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/install-privs-before)

This was because the files weren't being served correctly when navigating to the site locally.

Luckily I did not run this with sudo, but the output of the command listed many directories and files from /, /sys, /lib, /home and /proc (at which time I CTRL-C'd out of it).

I have tried to check a few permissions in directories like /sys, but I have no idea what they should be or if they changed. I have so far copied the output from the command to a file and can supply it if needed.

Basicly I just need to know of this command have caused any serious harm and if there is a way to restore the file permissions of those that I didn't want to change?

Comment: No there is no way to restore the file permission if you don't know in advance... but it seems it is not needed. All that your misspelled command did is to list a lot of files. I've tried with an harmful ' find . -exec '/usr/bin/md5sum {}' /;' and all that I Obtained is a list of file and not of md5sum...

Answer (score 0):

The famous answer of "it depends" applies here... Mostly, it'll depend on what user you ran the command as and if you ran the command exactly as you've written it above.

Check the very top of the output - I'm hoping you'll see something like:
`.`
`find: exec: No such file or directory`
`find: chmod: No such file or directory`
`find: 755: No such file or directory`
`find: {}: No such file or directory`

The scenarios:

- You actually typed `find . -exec chmod 755 {} \;` (Which is a valid command)
  The output of the command will only be the errors it encountered along the way, not the files it did manage to change.  If you ran it as yourself (ie a standard user with little to no permissions, just check the following directories:

  - Mail dir (probably `/var/spool/mail`)
  - Home dir (probably `/home/`)
  - Cron and at dirs (probably /var/spool/cron)
  - Maybe your temp dirs (`/tmp` and `/var/tmp`) but not vital unless you've got something in there that contains secrets.
- You typed the command as you wrote it above
  Don't worry, you're all good.  It tried to find all files in `.` and all files in `exec` and all files in `chmod`... you get the idea.  It'll just list them (along with a few permission denied errors) and change nothing.